# How can I set specific CSS classes for links which are images?

Tags: css, css-selectors

This seems painfully simple, but I can't work out how to do it:

I want every link on my site to have a specific style on mouseover, so I use

```
a:hover {
 /*style goes here*/
}
```

The thing is, I don't want that style applied to links that are images, but

```
a:hover img {
 /*reset style*/
}
```

doesn't work. What should I try instead?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I thought this might be the case.

Comment: I don't want to come off as bitter, because really I'm not. In fact, I would probably accept Sean Nyman's answer over my own. But, I have to ask, why did you accept the answer with the least information in it? Sean told you why what you were doing didn't work, and I gave you specific code.

Comment: Hey Scott: apologies, your answer is more detailed than Sean's. I'm new to Stack Overflow and was actually trying to work out how to accept multiple answers. I guess I went with Sean's rather that yours because it was sufficient to answer the question for me, but I appreciate that your answer is better overall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For links that are images, use a different css class instead of referencing all anchor tags.

Answer (score 4):

Your attempt is restyling the image element, not the a element, which is why it doesn't work (see [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching) for an explanation of CSS selector syntax).  Unfortunately, there is no syntax for selecting the parent of an element, so as others have said, you will have to create a special class for image links.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do it is to put a class on the `a`s that enclose `img`s, like so:

```
<a href="link.htm" class="imagelink"><img src="image.jpg" alt="Image" /></a>
```

And then select it in CSS with

```
a.imagelink:hover {
    /* styles */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
a:hover {
 /*link style goes here*/
}
```

Select all images with links when hovered and set another style.

```
a:link:hover img {
    /* hovered, linked image styles */
}
```

This will select only images that have links and are hovered over.

Works in Weebly as well.

Comment: ':link' pseudo-class selects all unvisited links, How this apply to links that are images?